# How to set the ArrayList<custom> data in to the ListView in another fragment which extends listView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist

How to set the ArrayList data in to the ListView in another fragment which extends listView?

**Help will be much appreciated from you experts out there.**

Custom ArrayList takes int, string, string.
I get the user input from two EditText's and add them to this ArrayList.
When user re-enters, it should keep adding it to the ArrayList.

Objective is to get all the entries from user and show it in a ListView in the next fragment.
But only the two Strings from the ArrayList into String array for the use as datasource for ArrayAdapter.
So overridden the toSting method in class diarylogs.
I can see the value from the ArrayList while sysout. 
**But, once i setListAdapter, the app crashes. Cannot understand what i am doing wrong.**

**UPDATE**

```
Class MainActivity extends Activity

//Static variable
public static ArrayList<DiaryLogs> test;
public static int Monday=0;
```

**Class DiaryLogs**

```
public class DiaryLogs {

    String timeEntry, entryEntered;
    int day;

    // single constructor that takes an integer and two string
    public DiaryLogs(int day, String timeEntry, String entryEntered) {
        super();
        this.day = day;
        this.timeEntry = timeEntry;
        this.entryEntered = entryEntered;

    }

    public String getTimeEntry() {
        return timeEntry;
    }

    public void setTimeEntry(String timeEntry) {
        this.timeEntry = timeEntry;
    }

    public String getEntryEntered() {
        return entryEntered;
    }

    public void setEntryEntered(String entryEntered) {
        this.entryEntered = entryEntered;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return timeEntry + "\n" + entryEntered;


    }
}
```

**Class Monday_fragment**

```
public class Monday_fragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.monday_fragment, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        currentDateTime();
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }

    public void currentDateTime() {
        EditText timeText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(
                R.id.dateTimeEText);
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy:H:m");
        String dateTime = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        timeText.setText(dateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        Button saveBtn = (Button) getView()
                .findViewById(R.id.saveDiaryEntryBtn);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                EditText timeText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(
                        R.id.dateTimeEText);

                EditText entryText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(
                        R.id.diaryEntryEText);
                String timeEntry = timeText.getText().toString();

                String entryEntered = entryText.getText().toString();

                MainActivity.test = new ArrayList<DiaryLogs>();

                MainActivity.test.add(new DiaryLogs(MainActivity.Monday,
                        timeEntry, entryEntered));

            }

        }

        );

        Button showBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(
                R.id.showDiaryEntriesBtn);
        showBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
                Monday_list_fragment mlf = new Monday_list_fragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mlf);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });

        super.onStart();
    }

}
```

**Class Monday_list_fragment**

```
public class Monday_list_fragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.monday_list_fragment, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

System.out.println(MainActivity.test); //test: if value can be seen

        ArrayAdapter<DiaryLogs> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<DiaryLogs>(
                getActivity(), 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MainActivity.test
                );
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter); //once i set adapter it crashes

    }

}
```

**layout XML file: monday_list_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/returnBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/return_mon_Btn" 
            android:onClick="monClick">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**LOGCAT**

```
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006): Process: com.example.s0217980_diary, PID: 10006
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.s0217980_diary/com.example.s0217980_diary.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at com.example.s0217980_diary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    ... 11 more
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at com.example.s0217980_diary.Monday_list_fragment.onCreate(Monday_list_fragment.java:45)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4786)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
04-11 23:45:53.992: E/AndroidRuntime(10006):    ... 21 more
04-11 23:48:11.294: D/dalvikvm(10069): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 71K, 6% free 3267K/3448K, paused 16ms, total 24ms
04-11 23:48:11.364: D/AndroidRuntime(10069): Shutting down VM
04-11 23:48:11.364: W/dalvikvm(10069): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0c9db20)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069): Process: com.example.s0217980_diary, PID: 10069
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.s0217980_diary/com.example.s0217980_diary.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at com.example.s0217980_diary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    ... 11 more
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at com.example.s0217980_diary.Monday_list_fragment.onCreate(Monday_list_fragment.java:45)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4786)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
04-11 23:48:11.374: E/AndroidRuntime(10069):    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array like ArrayList, you need not to unpack it and extract the string what you wanted and add it to another array just to input it to a listview. Just override the toString() method in your DiaryLogs class and return it with the strings of your choice (e.g. timeEntry & entryEntered). like

```
// class DiaryLogs
class DiaryLogs {
    ...
    @Override
    public toString() {
        return dateTime + " - " + entryName;
    }
    ...
}

// in your activity
ArrayList<DiaryLogs> diaryLogs = new ArrayList<DiaryLogs>();
diaryLogs.add(new DiaryLogs(1, "Apr. 14, 2014", "Entry 1"));
diaryLogs.add(new DiaryLogs(1, "Apr. 14, 2014", "Entry 2"));
diaryLogs.add(new DiaryLogs(1, "Apr. 14, 2014", "Entry 3"));

yourListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, diaryLogs));
```

yourListView is obviously the listview that you are using.

Comment: Thank you. But if you can please elaborate.